# How to do two variable numeric integration in Julia?

Tags: julia

I can do single variable numeric integration in Julia using `quadgk`.  Some simple examples:

```
julia> f(x) = cos(x)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> quadgk(f, 0, pi)
(8.326672684688674e-17,0.0)

julia> quadgk(f, 0, pi/2)
(1.0,1.1102230246251565e-16)

julia> g(x) = cos(x)^2
g (generic function with 1 method)

julia> quadgk(g, 0, pi/2)
(0.7853981633974483,0.0)

julia> pi/4
0.7853981633974483
```

The [documentation for quadgk](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/math/?highlight=cosh#numerical-integration) doesn't seem to imply an support for multidimensional integration, and sure enough I get an error if I attempt to misuse it for a 2D integral:

```
julia> quadgk( h, 0, pi/2, 0, pi/2)
ERROR: `h` has no method matching h(::Float64)
```

The documentation does suggest there are some external packages for integration, but doesn't name them.  I'm guessing that one such package can do two dimensional integrals.  What's the best such package for this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll want to check out the Cubature package:

https://github.com/stevengj/Cubature.jl

Arguably, `quadgk` should simply be removed from the standard library because it's limited and just misleads people into not looking for a package to do integration.

Comment: If I try:

using Cubature ; f(x) = cos( pi * sin(x[1]) * cos(x[2]) ) * sin(x[1]) ; hcubature(f, [0,0], [pi/2,pi/2])

then Julia appears to go into an infinite allocation loop (1Gb/minute).  Curiously with f(x) = cos( pi * sin(x[1]) * cos(x[2]) ), the integral succeeds.

Comment: The infinite allocation loop was a consequence of convergence failure.  It can be worked around by specifying an abstol parameter explicitly: hcubature(f, [0,0], [pi/2,pi/2], abstol=1e-8)

Comment: `cos( pi * sin(x[1]) * cos(x[2]) ) * sin(x[1])` integrates to zero over the specified `xmin` & `xmax` so the tolerance is never met.  Specifying `abstol` seems the easiest workaround.  You could also split the `xmin` and `xmax` into multiple regions and then sum the integrations.

Comment: Apparently others didn't agree that `quadgk` should be removed: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/10649; it should, however, be better documented and its help entry should include a reference to the Cubature package.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `Cubature.jl`, there is another Julia package that allows you to compute multidimensional numerical integrals: `Cuba.jl` (https://github.com/giordano/Cuba.jl).  You can install it using package manager:

```julia
Pkg.add("Cuba")
```

The complete documentation of the package is available at https://cubajl.readthedocs.org (also in [PDF version](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/cubajl/latest/cubajl.pdf))

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the package.

---

`Cuba.jl` is simply a Julia wrapper around [Cuba Library](http://www.feynarts.de/cuba/), by Thomas Hahn, and provides four independent algorithms to calculate integrals: Vegas, Suave, Divonne, Cuhre.

The integral of cos(x) in the domain [0, 1] can be computed with one of the following commands:

```julia
Vegas((x,f)->f[1]=cos(x[1]), 1, 1)
Suave((x,f)->f[1]=cos(x[1]), 1, 1)
Divonne((x,f)->f[1]=cos(x[1]), 1, 1)
Cuhre((x,f)->f[1]=cos(x[1]), 1, 1)
```

[As a more advanced example](https://cubajl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#vector-valued-integrand), the integral

[image]

where Ω = [0, 1]³ and

[image]

can be computed with the following Julia script:

```julia
using Cuba

function integrand(x, f)
    f[1] = sin(x[1])*cos(x[2])*exp(x[3])
    f[2] = exp(-(x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 + x[3]^2))
    f[3] = 1/(1 - x[1]*x[2]*x[3])
end

result = Cuhre(integrand, 3, 3, epsabs=1e-12, epsrel=1e-10)
answer = [(e-1)*(1-cos(1))*sin(1), (sqrt(pi)*erf(1)/2)^3, zeta(3)]
for i = 1:3
    println("Component $i")
    println(" Result of Cuba: ", result[1][i], " ± ", result[2][i])
    println(" Exact result:   ", answer[i])
    println(" Actual error:   ", abs(result[1][i] - answer[i]))
end
```

which gives the following output

```julia
Component 1
 Result of Cuba: 0.6646696797813739 ± 1.0050367631018485e-13
 Exact result:   0.6646696797813771
 Actual error:   3.219646771412954e-15
Component 2
 Result of Cuba: 0.4165383858806454 ± 2.932866749838454e-11
 Exact result:   0.41653838588663805
 Actual error:   5.9926508200192075e-12
Component 3
 Result of Cuba: 1.2020569031649702 ± 1.1958522385908214e-10
 Exact result:   1.2020569031595951
 Actual error:   5.375033751420233e-12
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try the [`HCubature.jl`](https://github.com/stevengj/HCubature.jl) package:

```
using HCubature
# Integrating cos(x) between 1.0 and 2.0
hcubature(x -> cos(x[1]), [1.0], [2.0])
# Integrating cos(x1)sin(x2) with domains of [1.0,2.0] for x1 and [1.1,3.0] for x2
hcubature(x -> cos(x[1]) * sin(x[2]), [1.0, 1.1], [2.0, 3.0])
```

Comment: Of note: `HCubature` seems to be the only package that can do 1. multidimensional integrals 2. of complex-valued functions.